# Is there any special setting of proxy server for WinInet API?

Tags: windows, winapi, proxy, wininet

I am using the WinInet API to get to internet files using HTTP. Everything works unless the user goes through a proxy server.

I'm using InternetOpen with INTERNET_OPEN_TYPE_PRECONFIG which is supposed to get and use the proxy info from the registry (according to the docs). Do I need to use INTERNET_OPEN_TYPE_PRECONFIG and specify the proxy specifically?

After InternetOpen, I call InternetOpenUrl and then InternetReadFile. Everything works great, except when user is using a proxy server.

What do I need to change to get it to work? Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

That's correct. I just use InternetOpen(0, INTERNET_OPEN_TYPE_PRECONFIG, 0, 0, 0) and it works. May be it isn't the proxy ?